# Drawing 2000 members from contact list freeze my app

Tags: android-contacts

I am developing an app need to read multiple contacts from phone contacts list. Suppose i have 2000 members add in my phonebook and i am succesfully get all contacts. but problem is that when i am drawing layout for 2000 contacts my device freeze untill all members not draw on screen.

Getting All contacts from Phonebook using contentResolver.

```
 public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr)
    {
        try {

             final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]
                     {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                     };

      final  String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
            name1.clear();
            phno1.clear();

            MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        });

  String lastNumber = "";
 Cursor c1 = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, selection, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
        while(c1.moveToNext())
        {
            try {
                String name = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String number = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                String test = number.replaceAll(" ", "");
                if (!lastNumber.contains(test)) {
                    lastNumber = test;
                    mc.addRow(new String[]{name, test});
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


            c1.close();

        while (mc.moveToNext()) 
{

    String value = "";
    String name    =mc.getString(mc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
String phoneNumber = mc.getString(mc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                String result = name.replaceAll("[!.#^$%&()+@_|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", " ");
                String test = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[!.#^$%&()+@_|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", "");

                String numbers = test.substring(Math.max(0, test.length() - 10));
                name1.add(result);
                phno1.add(numbers);

            }

            mc.close();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




Drawing contact layout from added contact to Arraylist.

 public void Drawcontactlayout()
    {
        try {

            contactlist.removeAllViews(); // Linear Layout

                    for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                            int endIndex = searchtext.length();
                            String nm = name1.get(i).toString();
                            String test1 = phno1.get(i).toString();
                            String s = searchtext.substring(0, endIndex);
                            String p = test1.substring(0, endIndex);
                            String n = nm.substring(0, endIndex);
                            String searchv = s.toUpperCase();


                            if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(s) || p.equalsIgnoreCase(s) || nm.contains(s) || nm.contains(searchv) || test1.contains(s) || searchtext.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                rl1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(ct);
                                layout.setLayoutParams(rl1);

                                final int finalI = i;
                                rl1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                TextView iname = new TextView(ct);
                                iname.setPadding(width / 70, 0, 0, 0);
                                iname.setId(i + 1);
                                iname.setText(name1.get(i).toString());
                                iname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                iname.setTextSize(12);
                                iname.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_light));
                                iname.setLayoutParams(rl1);

                                rl1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, iname.getId());
                                rl1.setMargins(width / 70, width / 70, 0, 0);
                                TextView mobile = new TextView(ct);
                                mobile.setId(i + 2);
                                mobile.setTextSize(12);
                                mobile.setText(phno1.get(i).toString());
                                mobile.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_light));
                                mobile.setLayoutParams(rl1);


                                rl1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width / 12, width / 12);
                                rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                                rl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                                rl1.setMargins(0, 0, width / 50, 0);
                                final TextView check = new TextView(ct);
                                check.setId(i + 3);
                                    try {
                                        if (checked) {
                                            check.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
                                            names.add(name1.get(finalI).toString());
                                            numbers.add(phno1.get(finalI).toString());
                                        } else {
                                            if (testing[finalI] != false) {
                                                check.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
                                            } else {
                                                names.clear();
                                                numbers.clear();
                                                check.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        check.setLayoutParams(rl1);
                                        checkbox.add(check);
                                    }catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                        try {
                                            if (CommanString.REMAINING == 0) {
                                                Toast.makeText(ct, "Insuficient Slot Invitees, please purchase more!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            } else {
                                                if (testing[finalI] == false) {
                                                    testing[finalI] = true;
                                                    names.add(name1.get(finalI).toString());
                                                    numbers.add(phno1.get(finalI).toString());
                                                    check.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);

                                                } else if (testing[finalI] == true) {
                                                    testing[finalI] = false;
                                                    Drawable img4 = ct.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
                                                    img4.setBounds(0, 0, width / 12, width / 12);
                                                    chkall.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, img4, null);
                                                    chkall.setCompoundDrawablePadding(width / 50);
                                                    isChecked = false;
                                                    checked = false;


                                                    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                                                        if (names.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name1.get(finalI).toString()) || numbers.get(finalI).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(phno1.get(finalI).toString())) {
                                                            // CommanString.REMAINING = CommanString.REMAINING +1;
                                                            names.remove(i);
                                                            numbers.remove(i);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    check.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);

                                                }

                                            }

                                        }catch (Exception e)
                                        {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                                rl1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, width / 300);
                                rl1.setMargins(0, width / 50, 0, 0);
                                TextView margin = new TextView(ct);
                                margin.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
                                margin.setLayoutParams(rl1);

                                layout.addView(iname);
                                layout.addView(mobile);
                                layout.addView(check);

                                contactlist.addView(layout);
                                contactlist.addView(margin);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To make the problem more understandable you should post some snippet of your code. But from your question it seems you must be using listview or RecyclerView (prefered as it is more efficient) to list all the contacts. When you display a lot of items in the list android don't draw layout for each each and every item separately(so it won't draw layout for all 200 contacts) for more information about how android generate layout for every item in RecylerView, you can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html).

The possible reason for freezing of app could be the loading of data on the UI thread. if you are doing task like loading lot of data from database or making http call to fetch data from network or any other intensive task you should use AsyncTask. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads or handlers. To learn about AsyncTask you can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)